# datagridview row selection; not updating to new selection

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Almost completed my first VB.Net program. Works great, with one problem. My datagridview displays info on selection of a row. However, it does not consistently change when user selects a different row. I have been selecting a third row, then going back to second row to get updated info.

here's my code so far. Any suggestions to update upon new selection??

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Me.txtCJISCode.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value
    Me.txtShortDescript.Text = DataGridView1.Item(10, i).Value
    Me.txtDescription.Text = DataGridView1.Item(23, i).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Selection mode of your datagrid, the `CurrentRow` might not be the selected one. Since you're doing it with the `CellContentClick` it would be easier to use the event args :

Replace

`i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index`

by

`i = e.RowIndex`